# Classify tweets in Java using Weka

Tags: java, twitter, machine-learning, classification

I have some tweets to do sentiment analysis. Thus, i fetched tweets by using Twitter4J then i decided to use Weka libraries for using methods like KMeans,Naive Bayes, SVM etc.

Firstly, i moved tweets into a text file by hand, and wrote their classes myself. This is my training data. In my code i read this file and tried to train and test my model. But i got the error

```
"Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: Cannot handle string attributes!"
```

To fix it i used StringtoWordVector filter but it didn't work either. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
import weka.classifiers.lazy.IBk;
import weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier;
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector;

public class Driver {
    public static BufferedReader readDataFile(String filename) {
        BufferedReader inputReader = null;

        try {
            inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("File not found: " + filename);
        }

        return inputReader;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("file.txt");

     Instances data = new Instances(datafile);
     data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);



     FilteredClassifier fc = new FilteredClassifier();

     /
     Classifier cModel = (Classifier)new IBk();   

     cModel.buildClassifier(data);

     StringToWordVector swv = new StringToWordVector();
     fc.setFilter(swv);
     fc.setClassifier(cModel);


     // Test the model
     Evaluation eTest = new Evaluation(data);
     eTest.evaluateModel(cModel, data);

     // Print the result à la Weka explorer:
     String strSummary = eTest.toSummaryString();
     System.out.println(strSummary);

     // Get the confusion matrix
     double[][] cmMatrix = eTest.confusionMatrix();
     for(int row_i=0; row_i<cmMatrix.length; row_i++){
         for(int col_i=0; col_i<cmMatrix.length; col_i++){
             System.out.print(cmMatrix[row_i][col_i]);
             System.out.print("|");
         }
         System.out.println();
     }
}
}
```

I also want to show my file.txt:

```
@relation twitter

@attribute tweetMsg string  
@attribute class{positive,negative,neutral}

@data

"bugün hava çok güzel",positive
"hiç iyi hissetmiyorum",negative
"hayat çok normal",neutral
"Diriliş Ertuğrul izlerken her türlü kumpasın döndüğünü görmek ama günün birinde Osmanlı Beyliği' nin kurulacağını bilmenin huzuru ?",positive
"Diriliş Ertuğrul dizisi ile tarihe merakim arttı ??",positive
"Kanka moralim bozuk diyorum boşver kanka gel diriliş ertuğrul izleyelim diyor yemin ederim kanka gibi kanka .",positive
"Diriliş Ertuğrul beni son zamanlarda futbol dışında TVde tutan tek yapım kurgusu, görseli süper",positive
"#kösemsultan Osmanlının gerçek yüzünü çıkardıkları için mi hoşunuza gitmiyor Diriliş Ertuğrul saçmalığın alası hadi onuda şikayet edin!!!",negative
"Benim için LeylaileMecnun neyse abim için Diriliş Ertuğrul da o.",neutral
"#MutlulukNeDiyeSorsalar diriliş Ertuğrul izlemek derim",positive
"beyler muhteşem yüz yıl kösemi izliyorum da diriliş ertuğrul bu diziye 10 takar. saray saray değil kadınlar hamamı sanki.",positive
"Diriliş Ertuğrul diziside ne boktan bir senaryo arkadaş. Herif 4 bölümde bir hain ilan edilip sonra obaya geri geliyor sonra yine hain :):)",negative
"Diriliş Ertuğrul izlemekten babama beyim dedim amk",neutral
"Diriliş ertuğrul haric bütün Türk dizileri saçmalik broo",positive
```

However, these tweets are in Turkish language. So, do you think i am going in right way? Or should i do something more complicated? Like firstly stemming the words etc.

Any help to my questions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Read the error message:

```
Cannot handle string attributes!
```

obviously refers to this line:

```
@attribute tweetMsg string
```

The classifier `IBk` does not support `string` attributes.

Comment: I saw but i've already tried another classifiers like Naive Bayes, J48, Logistic etc. None of them worked. I'm rather asking that is it the right way to do that ?

Comment: Yes, because you did not fix the problem of the string attribute. You need to vectorize it before training a classifier.